# Find Variable in Table with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, variables, while-loop

I am a beginner and I am trying to find a variable in a dynamic table with Selenium. I think it's not that hard, but I did something wrong, so maybe someone could take a look.
Here ist what I tried:

```
String  prioName = "AutoPrio";

//to get the number of rows
String row = "//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr";
int rowData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(row)).size();
                
//to get the number of columns 
String col="//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td";
int colData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(col)).size();
        

//search in Table for variable 
String firstPart = "//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[";
String secondPart ="]/td[";
String thirdPart ="]";
                
String text = null;
                
for (int i = 1; i <= rowData; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= colData; j++) {
        String finalPart = firstPart+i+secondPart+j+thirdPart;
        text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(finalPart)).getText();
        System.out.print(text+" / "); //This is working. Prints the table
        if (text == prioName) {
            System.out.println("Found in Table!"); //this is not working  
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

What it gives me looks like this:

- / Test / - /
- / test / 12 /
- / AutoPrio / 10 /
- / AutoPrio / 10 /

This ist just the Information, that is saved in the table

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check equality for text, you need to do `text.equals(prioName)` not `text == prioName`. For strings `==` will check if the objects are same or not, `equals(..)` method will check if the contents of the objects are same or not.